# Issue with selecting ancestors

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this HTML below How can I from `thing` get `checkall` ?

```
..
<input type="checkbox" class="checkall"><label>Check all</label>
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="thing"><label>Thing 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="thing"><label>Thing 2</label></li>
</ul>
...
```

I try `$(".thing").closest( ".checkall" );` but it didn't work It return it as `undefined` !
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23Bt2/)

**UPDATE** : [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/23Bt2/5/)

Comment: Watch out, you don't close your input tags

Comment: @Phil-R input tags are self closing.

Comment: Then shouldn't it end with /> ?

Comment: @Phil-R that's XHML strict compliancy. The slash is good practice, but not required. It can be an invalid element and still render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect selector. You need to use:

```
$(this).closest('ul').siblings('.checkall')
```

---

Using `closest` get's you to the closest parent, and the `input.checkall` element you are trying to get to, is a sibling to the parent of the `li.thing` element.

Read more about [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: That is because you have wrong code. I just fixed incorrect selector you were using.

Comment: you're right it return the right `.checkall` i have some error thanks for the answer man :)

Comment: I can't open a new subject can you help me with : why my jquery Object didn't get checked with

    `$('.checkall').checked = true ;`

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23Bt2/4/)

Comment: You need to use `$('.checkall').prop('checked',true)`